# Problem with @Autowired in JUnit Test on a Spring MVC project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit, autowired

Hi guys so here are my JUnit Test Class which doesn't get to autowire my DAO Class.
Bellow are my classes and the xml file for the MVC configuration:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Address;


public interface AddressDAO {

    public List<Address> findAllAdrressesOfCustomer(int customerId);

}
```

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.dao;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Address;

@Repository
public class AdrressDAOImpl implements AddressDAO {

    @Override
    public List<Address> findAllAdrressesOfCustomer(int customerId) {
        Address myAddress=new Address(6,"Mainstreet","12A","USA","Los Angeles","Los Angeles","41221") ;
        return Arrays.asList(myAddress);
    }

}
```

Here my Junit class that I want to use in order to test my AdressDAOImpl class:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.dao.AddressDAO;
import com.luv2code.springdemo.dao.CustomerDAO;

@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet_test.xml")
public class AddressDaoLayerTester {

    @Autowired
    AddressDAO myAddressDao;

    @Test
    public void testFindAllById() {
        assertTrue(!myAddressDao.findAllAdrressesOfCustomer(1).isEmpty());

    }

}
```

and here my xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:6703/my_first_db?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="24081983" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>



</beans>
```

So now comes my Problem, when I go ahead and call the class AddressDaoLayerTester I get the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.luv2code.springdemo.test.AddressDaoLayerTester': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myAddressDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.luv2code.springdemo.dao.AddressDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.luv2code.springdemo.dao.AddressDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 48 more
```

I also provide here the structure of my project:

[image]

**Obviously the stacktrace says that Spring can not autowire the AddressDAO class because he cannot find it, although it is there and it is correctly annotated.
Do you have any suggestion about the reasons that could cause this problem?**

Comment: I'm not sure why do you have an * there `@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:spring-mvc` ?

Comment: If I don't use it I get the following message: ```java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet_test.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist```

Comment: Ok, I got it. btw, I see that this code is from some udemy tutorial, I love that guy. But As I remember he didn't introduce maven and Junit. The point is that with maven the folders structure is more consistent and straighforward. There is a separate test folder with its resources folder, I suggest you to study it later, with maven/gradle, your resources will be loaded normally

Comment: Yeah you are right, I just wanted to use an old fashion project, I already studied the spring boot , which works quite straight forward, with out having to do all those configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `classpath*:` will silently return without any errors if it doesn't finds the file, may be it doesn't scans subdirectories and it couldn't find the xml. Try using `classpath*:com/**/<filename>.xml`

Comment: YOU ARE MY MAN !!!!! Thank you Yuvaraj that worked for me! But I don't get it, why couldn't he find my xml ?

Comment: The `classpath*:` prefix just says, find the xml's in different components from the same location followed by the prefix and combine it into one single context, whereas the wildcard usage after `classpath*:` prefix does more sophisticated pattern matching, see - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx-wildcards-in-resource-paths

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @Mock anotation instead of @Autowired. Also to test your repository you should stub your expected results:

```
when(myAddressDao.findAllAdrressesOfCustomer("id").thenReturn("your expected rusult")
```

Comment: Mocking the class that you're testing won't test that class.

Comment: @Beundead, yeah, i see that currently this repo return hardcoded values, but this is the way, how people usually test repo, if you want to test your repo, in your case the best way will be Repo repo = new Repo(), and then verify your method return values. You cannot autowire your bean in tests, even if you somehow do this, it will be bad approach and code style.

Comment: Hi @Oleg.  The `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` part should enable the `@Autowired`-ing of elements into a test class.  (Although I agree that I'd typically much prefer just a straight unit test.)